# Is there a definition of limiting flatness on a manifold?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am not talking about local flatness. Local flatness means an entire chart can be mapped to a flat euclidean space. For this reason for example a sphere is not flat, because any chart will still be curved. However a sphere does appear flat at the limit of the sphere size going to infinity. If you draw a small triangle on the surface of the earth the angles will approximately add to 180 degrees. As the triangle gets smaller the angles will approach a sum of 180.

Is there any way to make this notion precise? Do there exist riemmanian metrics where this is not true?

Comment: Every Riemannian metric is "infinitesimally flat" in the sense that you defined. But if you are willing to consider Finsler metrics, infinitesimal flatness no longer holds, unless the metric is Riemannian.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Interesting. Is there an official name for what I am talking about? Also is there a proof that all riemmanian metrics have this property?

Comment: I am not sure about the name, I would call it "infinitesimal flatness." I will write a proof in a day or so. The simplest proof is to embed $M$ isometrically in a Euclidean space $E^N$ of sufficiently high dimension and then "zoom-in" to the given point by rescaling the manifold in $E^N$. The sequence of rescaled manifolds will converge smoothly to a Euclidean subspace, hence, its triangles will converge to Euclidean triangles.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks and feel free to answer this question and I can mark it as resolved.